M Query parameters aren't connecting to my data slicers! Bind to Parameter?
I've spent a couple hours on a project today and I'm getting stuck on creating some date slicers for a Power Query I have in DirectQuery mode. I've seen a few people run into this but without a solution.
I'm connecting to an Oracle database and I have some M Query date parameters created for the user to select so that it can requery the database when these dates are changed. I have the dates split up into year, month, day so that there's the following parameters for a start and end date: startyear, startmonth, startday and endyear, endmonth,  endday. The datatype is set to text and accepts any value.
I created tables to go along with these so that I could have a slicer where users can change the dates from dropdown menus.
the year tables have the years 2020-2024, the month tables have the values 1-12, and day has values 1-31. These all are text and not numerical.
As I've seen in multiple videos, you can bind the fields to your parameters from the relationships page. I've done this for each table connecting year, month, and day tables to their respective parameters.I then created the slicers, but ran into my issue here: When I select a value from my slicer, it doesn't update the value of the parameter. The videos I've seen, one of them from microsoft, show the values updating according to the selected value. I can just update the values from Transform Data > Edit Parameters, but I would like to have a visual so that this is a feature in the published dashboard.
NOTE:

the data types are matching, text values in the table to text values in the parameters

the slicer is on the same page as the visuals it should be manipulating (I don't know if it would be an issue if they weren't since the slicers are supposed to change the query and not filter the visuals themselves)

I also tried selecting the year, month, and day tables as the query for suggested values in the manage parameters window, but that didn't help either


Has anybody else had an issue like this or have an idea where I'm going wrong?
Relationships Tab: Bind to Parameter:

Parameters table :

I also created this table to check the current values of my parameters, but no luck in trying to update them with slicers connected to column binds.
Is there some setting that I'm missing? Any other requirements for values to update via parameter binds and slicers?
